# Nightwatch assert present an anchor tag with class names

Tags: nightwatch.js

I'm trying to write a Nightwatch test targeting the following anchor tag:

```
<a class="ui label transition visible" data-value="PRIMARY" style="display: inline-block !important;">
Operational
<i class="delete icon"></i>
</a>
```

In Chrome's dev tools console, I can reference this anchor via
`$('a.ui.label.transition.visible')` where I get: `<a class=​"ui label transition visible" data-value=​"Operational" style=​"display:​ inline-block !important;​">​…​</a>​`

In Nightwatch, I cannot reference this anchor.

```
  'a simple test': function (browser) {
    const devServer = browser.globals.devServerURL
    browser
      .url(devServer+endpoint)
      .waitForElementVisible('.qpi-category-selector.ui.fluid.multiple.selection.normal.dropdown', 5000)
      .assert.elementPresent('a.ui.label.transition.visible')
      .end()
  }
```

Result:

```
FAILED: 1 assertions failed and  1 passed (29.052s)
   Testing if element <a.ui.label.transition.visible> is present. - expected "present" but got: "not present"
       at <anonymous>
       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
_________________________________________________

TEST FAILURE:  1 assertions failed, 1 passed. 31.138s

 ✖ study/test
 – QPI filter test (29.052s)
   Testing if element <a.ui.label.transition.visible> is present. - expected "present" but got: "not present"
```

Using Nightwatch 1.0.4

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: Can you check with only the class name and XPath .//a[@class='ui label transition visible']. And also can you use assert.visible. Eg: assert.visible('.//a[@class='ui label transition visible']')

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question because this is actually an issue with http vs https.

The test url was set to `http://localhost...` but our dev environment is set up to use `https`.

Without `https` our internal server was unable to communicate:

`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost.qdss.io:8080' is therefore not allowed access`

Hence, some of the anchor tags we expected to show up did not. I changed the url to `https` and used 
`chromeOptions: {
  args: ['disable-web-security', 'ignore-certificate-errors']
}`

**tldr: if Nightwatch is not picking up on something that should obviously be there, the problem is probably somewhere else.**